# Is it possible to make your own custom input types in an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I was wondering if I could make something like this: `<input type="secure">`. I want to know if it is possible to make a custom input type for my website.
I was going to use it to do things that you cannot normally do and style it with CSS and make it do what I want with JavaScript. Here is any example:

### CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
input[type="secure"] {
  background-color: #b5d1ff;
  border: 0.5px solid #f4a460;
  height: 1.6rem;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 0.4rem;
  padding-right: 0.4rem;
  width: 8.62rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
}
```

I haven't currently decided what I want to do with JavaScript but I think you get the idea.

Comment: The reason you shouldn't do that is while current browsers will treat "secure" the same as "text", there's no guarantee that future browsers will always do so, and instead start doing something weird with your input control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you don't really make a new type of input, you're simply creating a type that the browser/rendering engine doesn't know about and will ignore. But the CSS should apply to it as you have it.

However, I would suggest that you simply add a class to the input instead, if this is simply for styling purposes.

```
<input class="my-input" ...>

input.my-input {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, that's what classes are for. Even if 'technically you can', you'd be breaking compatibility and HTML standards compliance.

Answer (score 4):

You can create such an input, but unknown `type` value will be treated by browser as default `text` (logged to console). If you inspect DOM, you'll see `type="secure"`:

```js
const s = document.createElement('input');
s.setAttribute('type', 'secure');

document.body.appendChild(s);

console.log(s); // <input type="secure">

console.log('type: ', s.type); // type: "text"
```